# Create Event On Facebook page using Java script sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

**I am Looking for solution of my problem. after applying following code i am having error for permission

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB38Y.png)

```
FB.api("/me/events", 'post', eventData, function (response) {
            if (response.id) {
                alert("We have successfully created a Facebook event with ID: " + response.id);
            }
            return false;

        })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your code as text (formatted as a code-block). Linked images are not helpful to those who want to try to help you.

Comment: code-block editor giving me much errors help me to know more about it

Comment: You can enter two lines each of three back-ticks (`) and then just copy/paste your code text in between those two lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating Events is not possible with the API. At least not anymore, it was possible many years ago.

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events/#Creating